# Which bash shell options are used by the parser?

Tags: bash, shopt

Restricting our focus exclusively to `bash`, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283991) on Stack Overflow it is reported the following.

> `extglob` is a flag used *by the parser*. Functions, compound commands, &c. are parsed in entirety ahead of execution. Thus, `extglob` must be set before that content is parsed; setting it at execution time but after parse time does not have any effect for previously-parsed content.
>
> This is also why you can't run `shopt -s extglob; ls !(*.txt)` as a one-liner (when `extglob` is previously unset), but must have a newline between the two commands.

However, this is not true for other shell options. Consider e.g. the following.

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  .hiddenFile  file1  file2  file3
$ shopt dotglob
dotglob         off
$ echo *
file1 file2 file3
$ shopt -s dotglob; echo *
.hiddenFile file1 file2 file3
```

**Is it documented somewhere which shell options are used by the parser like `extglob` and therefore cannot be enabled within a group command that uses them?**

In the [`shopt` page in the `bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) nothing about the behaviour above seems to be mentioned.

Comment: You have a good point. `ls !(*.txt)` without `extglob` gets refused when the command is split into token, being a `bash` syntax error and therefore it is reasonable to guess that `extglob` has to be enabled before the content is parsed. For `echo *` this is not the case, because the parser knows how to interpret it. I wonder if the logic is always so trivial, though. Is it then the following a valid conclusion? *If the code runs fine without the shell option enabled, then such an option is not used by the parser.*

Comment: @AxelKrypton, `extglob` can change the meaning of a command line, it might not be the case that the alternative is always a syntax error. e.g. `!(foo)` is valid with and without extglob. If it "runs fine" depends on intent.

Comment: @ilkkachu Indeed, `!(foo)` is accepted by the parser with `extglob` disabled. I would then come back to my original question and be convinced that it would be interesting to know which shell option can and which cannot be enabled within a group command that uses it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it documented somewhere which shell options are used by the parser like extglob and therefore cannot be enabled within a group command that uses them?

It's hard to prove a negative, but I doubt there's a comprehensive list.

The ones I found that affect parsing are below, there may be others:

- `extglob` -- changes the meaning of the parenthesis, which are otherwise a special character
- `expand_aliases` -- aliases get expanded rather early in the processing
- `extquote` -- changes the meaning meaning of some quotes
- `interactive_comments` -- changes the meaning of `#` at the start of word.

Some of the `compat*` options might also have similar effects, but I'll leave testing them to someone more interested.

On the other hand, something like `dotglob`, `failglob` and `globstar` only affect the result of a glob, not how it's parsed.

Regarding `extglob`, a command line like `!(foo)` is valid either with `extglob` set, or without it. With it, it's a glob that matches all files but `foo`, and without it, it's a subshell running the command `foo`, with the return value inverted.

---

Note that in practice, this shouldn't be a problem. In a script, you can put the `shopt` command on a line of its own, so the changing in parsing affect the next line without problems. In a one-liner, you can use the `-O` option on the command line, e.g. in `bash -O extglob -c 'echo !(foo)'`, the extended glob works.

Comment: Your answer is a starting point. * you can put the `shopt` command on a line of its own, so the changing in parsing affect the next line without problems* - well, as I wrote in the question, this is not true inside a group command that uses it. And this is the relevant point in (complex) scripts. About `!(foo)`, it is different from `! (foo)` and your description applies to the second, I would say. Without a space, it should be seen as a history expansion, isn't it?

Comment: @AxelKrypton, can you clarify what you mean with a group command?

Comment: I took the expression from [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) in the `extglob` section (search for *group command* in the page). Since there is this link on [group command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Command.2BAFw_Grouping), I think the correct name is **compound command**. So, most keywords, sub shells, command grouping `{...}`, etc. Indeed, writing `shopt -s extglob` in an `if` clause and e.g. `echo +(*.txt)` in the same clause fails.

Comment: @AxelKrypton, ah yes, you're right. The shell reads and parses the whole compound command before executing any of it, and it does the same for _lines_, even though they're not compound commands in the same way. Hmm.