# Syntax error when "cp" statement with extended globbing options is moved to an "if" block

Tags: bash, wildcards

Having some trouble doing a copy in Bash. This works fine:

```bash
# Enable extended globbing and include filenames beginning with a '.'
shopt -s extglob dotglob
# Copy git repo to expected place
cp -r !($YOCTO_DIR) $POKY_DIR/$GIT_REPO_NAME/
```

But when I put an `if` statement round it:

```bash
if [ -z "$FROM_JENKINS" ]; then
    # FROM_JENKINS is blank, this is a local build

    # Enable extended globbing and include filenames beginning with a '.'
    shopt -s extglob dotglob
    # Copy git repo to expected place
    cp -r !($YOCTO_DIR) $POKY_DIR/$GIT_REPO_NAME/
fi
```

I get:

```
./build.sh: line 80: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Line 80 is the `cp`. If I remove the brackets it works:

```bash
    cp -r . $POKY_DIR/$GIT_REPO_NAME/
```

Why does the `if` statement not like brackets in `cp`?

Comment: Not related to your problem but you should quote all those variables.

Comment: Related: [Which bash shell options are used by the parser?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/573589)

Comment: @HaukeLaging, there's also the missing `--` and `failglob` option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem are the order and "range" of reading and executing.

The whole `if` block is just one command. So the shell has to read until the end of this command before it executes it.

That means that the rules **WITHOUT** `shopt -s extglob dotglob` (I am referring to the line here, not all of its content; as
ilkkachu points out in the comment: the `dotglob` is not relevant for the problem) are valid until the end of the `if` block because the `shopt` is executed afterwards only. And without the `shopt -s extglob` the `!(` is illegal there.

So you have to move the `shopt` before the `if` (and may revert it in an `else` branch).

Comment: I think it's mostly about `extglob`, since it changes the way the shell syntax is parsed. `dotglob` takes effect even if set inside the block. `shopt -u dotglob; if true; then shopt -s dotglob; echo *b*; fi` finds the file `.bbb`

Comment: @ilkkachu I didn't put that well (just fixed that). The difference is that `dotglob` changes the execution of the code only but not the parsing. So the dotglob is read without being executed immediately, too. But that is fine as the `echo` needs it for globbing only, not for the command parsing so being executed after reading the whole block is fine.

Comment: Better yet, pick *one* set of options and `shopt` them all at the top of your script. Don't play games with turning `extglob` on and off all over the place. It just makes the script longer and harder to read.